# Handle Text/csv file Output response in Postman with get Method

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have two get end points.

One retruns json output.

Second one with the same URL provides me data with text/csv. Using Produces annotation.

How to invoke the second get end point in Post man.

Comment: Add `Accept` header with csv value (and remove json)

Comment: Even if i use Accept header the request goes to the first endpoint. I get the Json response. How to differentiate two end points in POST MAN.

Comment: Can you show the endpoints code? If accept header didn't work, I guess there is something else

Comment: One point is like this /api/m1, another end point is api/m1 produces = {"text/csv" }.Same end point URL

Comment: This doesn't really help. You need to update the question with code samples. But I'm guessing that you did not add any `produces` on one endpoint? In this case, add it for JSON and do as suggested above.

Comment: By the way, if the code is the same for both endpoints, you can just add both `produces` on the same method.